# Strange javascript bug

Tags: javascript

Pls look at the following code:
html...

```
 <pre id='output'></pre>
```

html...

JS

```
 function log(text) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML += text + '\n';
 }

function foo() {

    var browser=0;
    if(navigator.appName.toUpperCase()=="MICROSOFT INTERNET EXPLORER")
        browser=1;
    else
    if(navigator.appName.toUpperCase()=="NETSCAPE")
        browser=2;
    log ('browser:'+browser);
    if (browser==1)
    {
        log ('IE');
    }
    if (browser==2);
    {
        log ('Chrome');
    }

    if (browser==0);
    {
            log ('Could not determine broweser type');
            return;
    }
  }
```

---

When I run this from IE the output is:
browser:1 ie not supported Chrome extension will be loaded Could not determine broweser type

When I run it from Chrome the output is:
browser:2
Chrome extension will be loaded
Could not determine broweser type

---

How can it be that browser has more than one value?
10xs,
Nir

Comment: Why do you use browser sniffing at all?

Comment: So in one case you run it from Chrome, while in the other case you run it from Chrome?

Comment: What's the difference between Chrome #1 and Chrome #2? Where does that (*not supported*) *Chrome extension will be loaded* come from, it's not in your code?

Comment: That code could not possibly produce that output, so what is the actual code and the actual output?

Comment: oops sorry: first output from IE - edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a very beginners mistake in your code

The `;` at the end of the if
`if (browser==0);` causes your if condition to end and the rest is a normal code block which gets executed every time no matter the value of `browser`

Comment: Clyde Lobo shows the correct answer. when you encounter JS issues, it's better to debug it with Developer Tool (F12) from your browsers. by setting a break point, it could be easy to find this code bug.

Comment: the same after `if (browser == 2);`

Answer (score 0):

You should not put `;` after an `if` statement: `if (browser==2);`